# I tried to hard wire power to pi 3 b, and smoked the board... File recovery?

Tags: file, recovery

I've been using my raspberry pi for about a year now, with Octoprint for my 3d printer. One of the more recent updates started showing it as under-voltaged. Over the last week, it started to cut out, and fail prints.

Figuring that this was due to the under-voltage issue, I found an article that showed how to hard wire 5.1v to the main board. I had some step-down converters (10A) lying around, so I set one up to 5.1v and soldered it to the connections on the bottom of the board, and hooked it up to my power supply.

Seemed to be working fine for a minute or so, then I noticed some smoke (never a good sign) coming from what I thought was the converter... I quickly disconnected the power, and started looking at my connections. It appeared that I maybe didn't have a good connection with the + end of the wire, so I re-soldered it, and tried again. This time, it almost instantly smoked at least one of the components on the Pi.

My question is this: I have several g-code files that I commonly use for printing that were stored on the pi's internal memory (I thought they were stored on the SD card, but not so much...). Is there a way to recover the files from the Pi? Or, do I need to start over, and get going on re-slicing the files I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Pi has no nonvolatile storage other than the SD Card.

Comment: `I thought they were stored on the SD card` you thought correctly. How have you searched for these files?

Comment: It is very likely that the regulated power supply hardware at the Rpi that created the smoke.  The SD card should be OK.  The simplest way is to use the SD card in another Rpi which can read it as before.  The Rpi SD card memory is "partitioned" in different formats which Windows tools can blindly read the image and write the image to another new SD card. But the Windows common tools cannot read the contents of the SD card.  So only experts can use special utilities to read the SD card when inserted in a Rpi or Windows PC USB SD card reader.

Answer (score 1):

All files are stored on the SD card. There is no other non-volatile storage on the Pi. Extracting the files from the SD card is tricky without booting from the SD card, so just pop it into another Pi, boot and retrieve your files.

Comment: Or in any Linux computer. Or boot from a bootable Linux flash drive.